# Run Oracle queries on Sublime Text 3

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run some queries in Sublime Text3.

I downloaded [this](http://lubriciousdevelopers.github.io/projects/sublime-sql-exec/#configuration) plugin, and I set up the settings:

```
{
    "connections": {
        "Connection 1": {
            "type"    : "oracle",
            "host"    : "127.0.0.1",
            "port"    :  1521,
            "username": "myuser",
            "password": "mypass",
            "database": "myschema",
            "service" : "What should I put here??"
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is: when I try to run (Ctrl+E+Ctrl+E) anything it says: **No active connection**.

My connection in SqlDeveloper: [image: My connection]

What should I add to make it work? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Take into account it what they said:
**"Some directories have to be defined in the PATH environment variable, according to the SGBD that you want to use.**", I made this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\oraclexe\\app\\oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\server\\bin\\sqlplus.exe", "-s", "myuser/mypass@myschema", "@$file"],
    "selector": "source.sql",
    "encoding": "cp1252"
}
```

Comment: Put the Oracle service name in there...

Comment: Yes, I added "xe" but still won't work.

Comment: "won't work" is not found in any error reference I know of.  What does your connection definition look like now, and what is the EXACT and COMPLETE error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Developer connection is working, then your database is not 'myschema', it is 'XE'.

Comment: Same error... By the way, I found a new plugin: http://mtxr.github.io/SQLTools/, but when I try to execute.. 
`File "./threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\SQLTools.sublime-package\SQLToolsModels.py", line 259, in run
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=open(self.tmp.name), env=os.environ.copy(), startupinfo=si)
  File "./subprocess.py", line 824, in __init__
  File "./subprocess.py", line 1118, in _execute_child
[WinError 2]`